# No video, only sound with VideoView

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

When I play a video file using a `VideoView` on Android, I can hear the sound fine, but the video does not show.

So, when I use :

```
myVideoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

then the video shows fine, however, then my `TextView` is behind the `VideoView` and I need it to be in front.

Therefore, I either need a solution so that the video is played without using `setZOrderOnTop`, or I need a way to get the text in front of the video while using `setZOrderOnTop`.

Answer (score 0):

```
videoView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```